# Playing video files on a panel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to play a video file on a panel. I located a sample code from [social.msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/caf245b9-a7f9-42b1-9276-f8dfc1e21591/playing-a-midi-file?forum=Vsexpressvb) but the download links to directx redistributable & SDK update mentioned on the sample code is broken. Therefore I manually searched for directx 9.0C and installed it from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34429). And below is the code that I used.

```
Imports Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback

Dim videoFile As Video = New Video("G:/Shared Data/myvid-2012.avi")
videoFile.Owner = Panel1
videoFile.Play()
```

I had to manually browse & add the reference of `Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback`.

The above code is in the form load event. Now when I try to run the application it sometimes holds forever without opening my app. And sometimes it does open up but my panel doesn't show up the video. Is there a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Don't know if it will help, but what if you try using SlimDX instead? http://slimdx.org/

Comment: there is also  DirectShowNET

Comment: @Plutonix thanks but isn't there a simpler way to do this directly from vb.net, playing a video seems a typical requirement. Can't believe vb.net doesn't have a simpler solution for this. I tried using windows media player, & it lags a lot while playing the video.

Comment: That link to "DirectX 9.0c" is ancient and only applies to Windows XP RTM, Windows XP Service Pack 1, or older version of the OS. It does *nothing* on Windows XP Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2003 Server 1, or later. It doesn't even install the legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies you are trying to use.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you took a dependency on the .NET Managed DirectX wrappers that Microsoft published back in the .NET 1.0 days.  It was a troublesome library and they discontinued it 10 years ago.  The problem you describe sounds like "loader lock", that library had a chronic problem with it.  The probable reason it was discontinued.  There is no "official" .NET wrapper for DirectX but open source projects took on the challenge.  SharpDX and SlimDX were the most popular ones.

Video playback technology moved fast, pretty important to not get stuck on the old stuff.  There are many, many alternatives.  The canonical modern solution for desktop apps is described in [this howto article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969812%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Not a panel of course, I have to recommend to stay away from DirectShow wrappers today.  You can easily embed Windows Media Player, well described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If AVI playback is your only requirement then the popular [AForge.NET library](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/) might be suitable, AVIFileVideoSource class.

Comment: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969812%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is this a wpf example because it says MediaPlayer is not defined, or do I need to add some reference. I tried the windows media player it also lags when playing the video.

Comment: I am trying to play a repeating video in my log-in screen to add a more attractive appearance to my application, therefore I don't want a compromise in performance due to visual appeal object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the *june 2006 directx SDK* which I believe is the last sdk for managed directx

[DirectX SDK-(June 2006)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1638)

In your form load event:

```
Dim sz As Size = New Size(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)

Dim videoFile As Video = New Video("G:/Shared Data/myvid-2012.avi", False)
videoFile.Owner = Panel1

videoFile.Play() 'changes the size of panel

'Set the original size
Panel1.Size = sz
```

Comment: Don't use legacy Managed DirectX 1.1. See [DirectX and .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I didn't say it is the best solution. Nor did I say that it *should be* used. On the other it is the only way to use *AudioVideoPlayback* which the OP uses, and it works with its limitations. It is a direct answer to the OP question. If you have a different modern solution I am waiting to see your answer.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn. Will there be a huge performance impact in using this. I am intending to play this video on the background of my app purely for a visual appealing activity & I don't won't the video to lag or my application to lag because of this. Anyways I will download DirectXSDK (pretty big file) and try it out. Thanks.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε. Since you mentioned not to use Managed DirectX, I would be glad to use a more modern approach, BTW I am using Winforms not WPF, looking forward to your answer too.

Comment: On Windows Vista or later, you should use Media Foundation, but I don't know what your system requirements. The general advice is to use the Media Player ActiveX control see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953.aspx).

Comment: This may also have something to do with Mixed Mode assembly:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2bf0c6c3-e01f-45ba-ab75-d81e7a07255b/systeminvalidoperationexception-mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v114322-of-the?forum=vbgeneral

Answer (score 0):

[image: You can open the following]

Replace everything in your App.Config File With the following(For .net Framework 4.0)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```